# Is it 'to reach' or 'reach'?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a sentence that I'm confused about

```
She has helped the organization to reach its goals...
```

or

```
She has helped the organization reach its goals...
```

Which one is correct? And do explain why if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentencs are correct and essentially interchangeable.
The slight nuance might be that using "***to***" sounds a bit more aspirational or that without *something* it may not have been possible.

> We help high school students **to** become valuable members of society

Comment: That's a good point about *[help] **to** [verb]* perhaps implying that the action might not have been possible without help. It's not mentioned in [your previous answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76155/126) to an earlier ELL question on the same issue, but I could easily convince myself it might sometimes be a factor. Increasingly we tend *not* to include ***to*** (back in KJV it was *He maketh me **to** lie down in green pastures,* but we never include it with ***make*** today), so arguably people look for / invent your "nuance" to explain the *slightly* "unusual" inclusion today.