# Omitting "to" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I read this sentence:

"They all helped load up the car."

I cannot understand why "to" is missing here. As "They all helped to load up the car."

I can be wrong but "to" makes more sense to me. But there must be some point behind omitting "to" that I cannot understand and need help with.

Comment: Generally, the verb "help" can take either a _to_-infinitival clause or a bare infinitival one as complement. "They all helped (to) load up the car".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help to do something or help do something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47221/help-to-do-something-or-help-do-something) Also [help you do (or) to do something - difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27560/help-you-do-or-to-do-something-difference), and probably others.

Comment: This might be helpful https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47223/3463